# Linear Algebra: Distance between two parallel lines

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

Find the distance between the two (obviously parallel) lines below where $\alpha ,\beta \in \mathbb R$ are scalars.
$$\text{Line #1}:\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}+\alpha\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\text{Line #2}:\begin{bmatrix}1\,\\-1\\3\,\end{bmatrix}+\beta\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

How do I find the required distance? Please give me advice.

Comment: Have you tried finding a perpendicular line to your two parallel lines?

Answer (score 3):

**Pick point on the first line.**

$P_{1}= [1,2,2]$

**Pick point with parameter $\beta$.**

$P_{2}= [1,-1,3] + \beta[1,1,0]$

**Make a function   $ f$($\beta$) which describes distance between these two points.**

$ f(\beta) = $ $\sqrt[]{ (1-1-\beta)^2 + (2+1-\beta)^2 + (2-3)^2 }$

**Find minimum of this function.**

min$f(\beta) = \sqrt{11\over2}$

So the distance is $\sqrt{11\over2}$

$$$$$$$$
--- how to find minimum:

square function is strictcly monotonic, and values of function under square root $\in R+$  so we can find min of

$ f(\beta) = { (1-1-\beta)^2 + (2+1-\beta)^2 + (2-3)^2 }$

simplify

$ f(\beta) =  2\beta^2 - 6\beta + 10 $

this function has minimum which is y of the vertex of parabola

y = $[-\Delta]\over{4a}$

$\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$

so we have $\Delta= 36-4\times 2 \times 10 = -44$

min f($\beta$)=$\sqrt{y}$= $ \sqrt{44\over 8} $=$ \sqrt{11\over2}$

Comment: It might be worth mentioning *how* you can find the minimum. There are several ways. Which do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the angle between your lines and $OX$, you can [rotate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29) the lines to make them parralel with $OX$ or $OY$.

After this, just calculate the difference between the cordinates.